# "Flattening" a databag in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, udf, databags

Suppose I have a bunch of databags generated from a Pig UDF that holds several tuples of Strings. How can I pull all of them out of the databags and simple make each String its own "row" of data.

`databags = FOREACH data GENERATE pigUdfThatMakesDataBags(data::someText);
strings = FOREACH databags { ??? };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
databags = FOREACH data GENERATE pigUdfThatMakesDataBags(data::someText);
datatuples = FOREACH databags FLATTEN($0);      -- Bag to Tuples 
strings = FOREACH datatuples FLATTEN(TOBAG(*)); -- Tuples to Tokens'
DUMP strings;
```

Answer (score 1):

Am I understand it right that you're looking for the [FLATTEN](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Flatten+Operator)?